# A word or phrase for wildly overreacting against a legitimate wrongdoing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm not sure if the phrase I'm looking for would be combat related or not, but essentially I'm looking to describe a situation like the following examples:

1. A drunk man shoves a sober man to get past him, and the sober man reacts by knocking out the drunk man's teeth.
2. A wife cheats on her husband, so the husband kills her.
3. Dissident civilians throw rocks at soldiers, the soldiers shoot the civilians dead with machine guns.

Comment: Sounds like disproportionate retaliation.

Comment: What is wrong with "overreact"?

Comment: Were they non-lethal rocks?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ask Goliath...

Comment: Not sure it has all of what you're looking for (esp. "legitimate wrongdoing"), but the colloquial American *to go ham* might work: "A drunk man shoves a sober man to get past him; the sober man went ham and knocked out the drunk man's teeth."

Comment: “Went bezerk.” .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **overkill** should suit your purpose

> You can say that something is overkill when you think that there is more of it than is necessary or appropriate.

[Collins]

Answer (score 0):

[***Over-react***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overreact)

...as in your question is the best answer.

> to react to something too strongly : to respond to something with too strong an emotion or with unnecessary or excessive action

-Merriam Webster

and as [@Yosem Baskin](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/215927/yosef-baskin) said in a comment

> "Sounds like disproportionate retaliation."

...if you want to get fancy.